# adding delete button to appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is attached below.

```js
$('#aprod').on('click', function() {
    $('#ln1').clone().appendTo('#page3_inside');
    prodnum = prodnum + 1;
    $('#conf_prodnum').val(prodnum);
});

$('body').on('click', '.del', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type='button' value='Add Another Product' id='aprod' />
    </form>
    <table id='page3_inside'>
        <tr id='ln1'>
            <td>
                <label for="product_name">Product Name</label>
                <br />
                <select class='input name_of_product' style='width:150px; height:34px;' name="name_of_product[]">
                    <option value="">Select from List</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="product_cat">Product Category</label>
                <br />
                <input type='text' class="input product_category" name="product_category[]"
                style="font-family:verdana; width:150px; border: 1px solid #000000;" readonly="readonly" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="qty">Qty</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" value="" class="input qty" style="width:100px;" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty"
                onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="unit">Unit</label>
                <br />
                <input type='text' class="input unit" style="width:100px;" name="unit[]" readonly="readonly" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="brand">PO Number</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" value="" class="input po" name="po[]" placeholder="PO Number"
                style='width:150px; height:28px;' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src='http://www.oasisservicedoffices.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Delete-button-150x150.jpg'
                class='del' width='30px' style='cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$('body').on('click', '.del', function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

I created a delete button for appended elements. but as you can see, there is a delete button on the first row. what i want to do is remove that delete button, and only display it on the next row upon pressing the 'Add Another Product' button.

```
 $('#aprod').on('click', function() {
   $('#ln1').clone().appendTo('#page3_inside');
   prodnum = prodnum + 1;
   $('#conf_prodnum').val(prodnum);
});
```

Comment: you expacting to not show all about the last one or just this first one should not show ?

Comment: Alternatively, you may consider showing the delete button when the row is not empty (i.e. nothing filled in yet) and disabling the add button if there's at least one empty row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just hide the first delete button with css

```
table tr:first-child .del{
    display: none;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/f772sovm/11/)

Comment: @KimCarlo : Are you sure this solution is working for you when multiple products has been added?
In my opinion, It will work only when max 2 products can be added at a time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `delete` button to the last element only:

```
$('#aprod').on('click', function() {
    var el = $('#page3_inside tr:last').clone()
    $('#page3_inside').find('.del').remove();
    el.appendTo('#page3_inside');
    prodnum = prodnum + 1;
    $('#conf_prodnum').val(prodnum);
});

$('body').on('click', '.del', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/f772sovm/8/

Comment: When you delete first row then add another product doesn't  working

Answer (score 1):

You can append the `img` directly in JS. Remove it from your HTML.

```
$('#aprod').on('click', function() {
    var i=$('#ln1').clone().appendTo('#page3_inside');
    i.append('<img src="http://www.oasisservicedoffices.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Delete-button-150x150.jpg" class="del" width="30px" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">')
    prodnum = prodnum + 1;
    $('#conf_prodnum').val(prodnum);
});
```

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f772sovm/10/)***

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$( "#page3_inside table" ).first().find('img').css("display", "none");
```